# Multinomial mixed effects logistic regression

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression, mixed-models, multinomial

Are there any packages that perform multinomial logistic mixed-effects regression in Python? pymer4 can do mixed-effects logistic regression, but I couldn't find a package that implements the multinomial version of this.